# Google Maps API Bounding Box doesn't expand to full size

Tags: google-maps

I am using Googles Map API v3. 
Can somebody explain the behavior of the map's bounding boxes to me?

Depending on the zoom level these bounds behave weird - when I zoom in it works as expected - the bounds stretch from the lower left corner of the pane to the upper right corner. As soon as I zoom out it get weirds - the bounding box splits up. You can reproduce this with the google examples and the attached code. Just zoom out until the maximum.

The wrong bounding boxes are really annoying - e.g. markers in between are not in the bounds of the map, although they are visible.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple.html

http://www.spotdiving.com/bug.png

```
var viewportBox;
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'idle', function(event)
{
    var bounds = map.getBounds();

    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

    var viewportPoints = [
        ne, new google.maps.LatLng(ne.lat(), sw.lng()),
        sw, new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat(), ne.lng()), ne
    ];

    if (viewportBox)
    {
        viewportBox.setPath(viewportPoints);
    } else
    {
        viewportBox = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: viewportPoints,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 4
        });
        viewportBox.setMap(map);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you delete viewportsPoints? Why come that it has more then 2 coordinates?

Comment: I never delete the viewportPoints, but it's local anyway, isn't it? It has more because it spans the rectangle. Google seems to replicate the viewport when a user zooms out too far, but I still can't figure out how I am supposed to check if a marker is visible, when the bounding box is not full-size.